# python subprocess with /dev/zero input

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write in python the following command :
netcat ip port < /dev/zero
it works in terminal and so far my attempts in python failed miserably
any hints please ?

```
fd = os.open("/dev/zero", os.O_RDONLY);
buf = os.read(fd, 1024)
os.close(fd)
ip='192.168.1.45'
port= 56
netc =subprocess.Popen(['netcat',ip,str(port)],stdin=buf)
```

Comment: you could use `s = socket.create_connection((ip, port));` `while True: s.sendall(buf)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdin needs to be a python file object. Fortunately, there is one handy...

```
import subprocess

ip='192.168.1.45'
port= 56
with open("/dev/zero", "rb", 0) as file:
    netc = subprocess.Popen(['netcat', ip, str(port)], stdin=file)
```